# How to Disable Elastic User access in Kibana Dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am trying to setup Elastic search log management...
I have enabled *Free Xpack secutiry* for *kibana* Dashboard authentication and created users with super access for my team members.. Now I would like to disable elastic user login access in *kibana* Dashboard..

So  elastic user access will work only beat's & Logstash  configurations.

How can I disable elastic user *kibana* Dashboard access?

Answer (score 1):

Read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/ls-security.html) link. Create a separate user with privileges required to only index data and use them in the output plugin for logstash and beats.